# How create global object in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am have one class named country , it has three `NSMutableArray` country_name, latitude and longitude. i need the object of country class in whole application. So how to declare country class object as **global object**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see this tutorial:

[Creating a global object in objective-C](http://www.learningiphone.com/2009/09/creating-a-global-object-in-objective-c/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [singleton design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and make a global object. But in general global variables / objects / singletons are a hint that something with your design is wrong.

Create a singleton this way:

```
+ (CardPainter*) sharedPainter { 
    static CardPainter* sp; 
    static dispatch_once_t token; 
    dispatch_once(&token, ^{  
        sp = [[CardPainter alloc] init]; 
    });
    return sp; }
```

Comment: hey dear, i have one Confusion. where i should create object of `cardPainter` class to use it globally?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend singleton like solution. Here is apple documentation with some explanation.

http://alexefish.com/post/15968663296/understanding-and-creating-singletons-in-objective-c